# Fitnesse - disable [?] create new page option in tables

Tags: fitnesse

I have test data that is Pascal Case.

```
|Verify Objects|
|Name|Value|InitialName |...|
|A   |B    |AlphaName[?]|...|
```

How do I remove the automatic `[?]` feature that is showing up for my test data? It is causing it to fail verification.

I tried spacing the words out, which stopped `[?]` but now the data is wrong. Surrounding the words in quotations also worked, but then the data is wrong as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by adding `!` to the beginning of the fixture:

```
!|Verify Objects|
|Name|Value|InitialName |...|
|A   |B    |AlphaName[?]|...|
```

Found the answer in a discussion [here](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fitnesse/conversations/topics/1293).

Comment: That is the primary solution.  You can also do !-AplhaName-! without marking the whole table, if that would break something else you need interpreted.

Comment: Hey @Dan, thanks for the comment. That alternative solution is exactly the issue I just ran into and is the fix I was looking for!